# Get value from Ansible structure

Tags: ansible

I have the following output when running a playbook with debug :

```
TASK: [debug lb data]    ***********************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "var": {
        "lb": {
            "balancer": {
                "algorithm": "LEAST_CONNECTIONS",
                "contentCaching": {
                    "enabled": false
                }
                "virtual_ips": [
                    {
                         "address": "10.0.0.1",
                         "id": 123,
                         "ip_version": "IPV4",
                         "type": "PUBLIC"
                    }
                ]
            }
     }
}
```

How can one get variable "address" so it can be used later on as an input for another variable?

For example:

```
- name: Create A record
  local_action:
    data: "{{ address }}"
    type: A
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the it like that:

`- name: Create A record
  local_action:
    data: "{{ lb.balancer.virtual_ips.address }}"
    type: A`

this is a documentation from ansible docs:

> Accessing Complex Variable Data
>
> We already talked about facts a little higher up in the documentation.
>
> Some provided facts, like networking information, are made available as nested data structures. To access them a simple {{ foo }} is not sufficient, but it is still easy to do. Here’s how we get an IP address:
>
> ```
>    {{ ansible_eth0["ipv4"]["address"] }}
> ```
>
> OR alternatively:
>
> ```
>    {{ ansible_eth0.ipv4.address }}
> ```
>
> Similarly, this is how we access the first element of an array:
>
> ```
>    {{ foo[0] }}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I also found this works pretty well:

```
{{hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_dns']['nameservers'][0]}}
```

Using

```
{{hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_dns']['nameservers']}}
```

Would include some additional annoying characters :-)